# SpringBoot app failng in WLS12c/Java8/RHEL fedora7.5 with Failed to read schema document http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, xsd, weblogic12c

I am trying to deploy springboot application (bundled as war) in Web logic 12c.
below are the configuration:
RHEL fedora 7.5
Java 8

When I am trying to deploy it on above machine, its failing with error

```
<Warning> <org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap> <BEA-000000> <WELD-001210: Warning 
when  validating file:/abc/.../war/WEB-INF/beans.xml@17 against xsd. 
schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 
'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd', because 1) 
could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root 
element of the document is not <xsd:schema>
```

War is built using **java7**.

But the same war works on weblogic12c/java8 on windows 10 platform

**beans.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
  xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
     http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
     http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
     http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">


<bean id="someClass" class="com.somepackage" />
<bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider"/>
<jaxrs:server id="someService" address="/ser/v1.0">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="someControllerClass" />          
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
         <jaxrs:providers>
                <ref bean='jsonProvider' />
        </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

I tried adding this on top

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans>
```

but that also didnt work.

Comment: I wouldn't call it `beans.xml` (as that is also the magic name used by CDI). Next make sure that you have your classloading set properly and ignore the classes from weblogic (it ships with its own Spring version).

Comment: @M.Deinum  Thanks for the reply.Can you please elaborate on the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @M. Deinum comment, I changed beans.xml file to other name and it started working.